# Ball under the water jet

Tags: rotational-dynamics, water, rotational-kinematics

What is the name of the physical principle that show that a ball under a water jet (for example in a bathtub) rotates but does not move?

I am not able to find any video of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a video [that shows the ball behaviour you're describing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OVrsUY8aUQ)

The phenomenon is explained by the Coandă effect: the tendency of a fluid jet to stay attached to a convex surface.

Note that the ball *does actually move* in a kind of oscillatory motion. This is probably due to the water jet in the video not being highly stable. When more liquid is running over one side of the ball, viscous friction causes a net torque on the ball and by Newton's second law it then must start to rotate.

The Coandă effect can also be used to balance a ball on *top* of a water jet.